Equivalent of spacy similarity function in langchain
I'd like to use langchain for a check of similarity between two sentencies. So far, I'm doing it with Spacy, like in the docs: https://spacy.io/universe/project/spacy-universal-sentence-encoder
import spacy_universal_sentence_encoder
# load one of the models: ['en_use_md', 'en_use_lg', 'xx_use_md', 'xx_use_lg']
nlp = spacy_universal_sentence_encoder.load_model('en_use_lg')
# get two documents
doc_1 = nlp('Hi there, how are you?')
doc_2 = nlp('Hello there, how are you doing today?')
# use the similarity method that is based on the vectors, on Doc, Span or Token
print(doc_1.similarity(doc_2[0:7]))

Is there an equivalent for that in langchain?
